# Click on a title and replace its last letter using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Clicking on a title should replace its last letter with `*`. In the example below the results should be `gol*`, `silve*`, `su*`. Any help?

```js
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  let a = $(this).text();
  //let b = a.replace_last_letter_with "*"
  $(this).text(b)
});
```

```css
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>gold</div>
<div class='title'>silver</div>
<div class='title'>sun</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this work using [`String.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  $(this).text(function(i, t){
    return t.slice(0, -1)+"*";
  });
});
```

```css
.title{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>gold</div>
<div class='title'>silver</div>
<div class='title'>sun</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works, what if I need to replace all letters with a `*`, pls?

Comment: @puerto If you mean replace `gold` to `*`, you need to use `$(this).text("*")` but if you mean `****` so you should use `.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple Regex to select the last letter of the text and set it to `*`. Also note that you can provide a function to `text()` which accepts the current value as an argument and returns the new value to set. Try this:

```js
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, t) {
    return t.trim().replace(/.$/, '*');
  });
});
```

```css
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>gold</div>
<div class='title'>silver</div>
<div class='title'>sun</div>
```

Comment: So there is a strong competition between `trim` and `slice`. Seems there is no any real criteria to decide - which answer to accept. Except - maybe a general rule - the lower  reputation score. Hope you agree.

Comment: `trim()` should be used in both answers to remove whitespace. The choice is between `slice()` and a regular expression. Also answers should be judged purely on merit, not the rep of the answerer, but it's your choice.